# Is it possible to replace malloc on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'd like to use a custom `malloc` and `free` for some allocations in an iOS app, including those made by classes like `NSMutableData`.

- Is this possible?
- If so, how do I do it?

---

<sub>What I'd actually like to do is zero out certain data after I've used it, in order to guarantee forward security (in case the device is lost or stolen) as much as possible. If there's an easier way to do this that doesn't involve replacing `malloc` then that's great.</sub>

<sub>I believe I need to replace malloc in order to do this because the sensitive data is stored in the keychain --- and I have no option other than to use `NSDictionary`, `NSString` and `NSData` in order to access this data (I can't even use the mutable versions).</sub>

Comment: It might help if you told us why?

Comment: @deanWombourne I'm interested in securing data, specifically, wiping it from RAM once it has been encrypted, and similar tasks.

Comment: You're anticipating someone monitoring the RAM of an iOS device - if so, what's stopping them monitor RAM during encryption and get the data then? And if they have access to RAM we can assume they have controller of the processor so can see registers etc - if they have that kind of control, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @deanWombourne I'm anticipating the device falling into evil hands **after** the encryption is complete, and the message has been sent to the other party. I care about forward security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of overwriting generic memory management functions you can use custom allocators on the sensitive objects.

The keychain services API is written in C and uses Core Foundation objects, like CFDictionary, CFData and CFString. While it's true that these objects are "toll free" bridged to their Objective-C counterparts and are usually interchangeable they have some abilities not available from Objective-C. One of these features is using custom allocators.

`CFDictionaryCreate` for example takes an argument of type `CFAllocatorRef` which, in turn, can be created using `CFAllocatorCreate`. The allocator holds pointers to functions for allocation and deallocation, among others. You can use custom functions to overwrite the sensible data.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to go so low-level about it? I'd just overwrite the data in the NSMutableData instance with zeroes instead. If you really need to mess with malloc - I'd probably write a category on NSObject and override the memory-handling functions.

Comment: Because I have to use NSString, NSDictionary, NSData etc. in the keychain services API. I'm open to easier ways of doing it: I'm also fairly new to objective-c: what's a category, and how would I use one to override memory-handling?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have no iOS experience, but I understand that it uses GCC. Assuming that is correct...

I have done this, albeit with GCC on the PlayStation3. I don't know how much of this is transferable to your case. I used the GCC [objcopy](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html#objcopy) utility with `--weaken-symbol`. (You may need to use [nm](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html#nm) to list the symbols in your library.

Once you've "weakened" the library's malloc, you just write your own, which is then used instead of the original when linked (rather than giving you a link error). To delegate to the original you may have to give it another name somehow (can't remember -- presumably doable with one of the [binutils](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/index.html) or else there's both a `malloc` and a `_malloc` in the library -- sorry, it's been a while.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: unfortunately Apple gcc doesn't include binutils, it has `otool` instead, which afaik can't change symbol visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to use the Objective-C memory management system based on ownership (retain/release). [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Another option would be to use C structures with C memory management rules like malloc.

Comment: I'd like to replace the underlying allocator: szone_malloc, or whatever. Using c entirely for the relevant portion of the application is one option.

Comment: I'd recommend you to implement the security logic in C and only the UI with Objective-C. You can use them in the same project, with 'c' file extension to C code and 'm' file extension to Objective-C code.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableData methods like dataWithBytes:length use calloc / bzero internally already. Is that good enough for you?

Comment: What's more important is what happens when the object is freed: presumably it doesn't go to the effort of zero-ing out it's data then?